# NPE in setText with TextView with AsyncTask in onPostExecute inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm having a problem: I am developing an android app where I have to parse some information.I am parsing information from a url using AsyncTask, I've succesfully parsed some info and in the method `onPostExecute()` I call a method that displays the parsed info in a TextView that will be displayed in a Fragment. My app is separated by Fragments, but everytime I run my app I get a NullPointerException in the line where I set the text in a TextView called title.
In `onPostExecute` I call the method `displayText()` and inside this method, I update the title variable. Here's part of the code so you can easily understand:

**This is the Fragment**

```
public class WeatherActivity extends Fragment{

TextView title;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_activity, container,false);
    title=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherTitle);
    return view;
}

public void displayWeather(Weather weather){
    title.setText(weather.getTitle());//this is the line that gives me the NPE
}
}
```

**This is the class that makes the parsing**

```
public class WeatherManager extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

public static final String WEATHER_URL="some url";
Weather weather;
WeatherActivity wa=new WeatherActivity();
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    loadXML();//does the parsing
    return null;
}

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    wa.displayWeather(weather);//calls to update fragment
}

public void loadXML(){
    //does all the work and returns the info in an object weather
}

}
```

This is my xml. For the moment, I only have one TextView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weatherTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

And this is my LogCat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27441): Process: com.example.test23, PID: 27441
E/AndroidRuntime(27441): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(27441):    at com.example.test23.WeatherActivity.displayWeather(WeatherActivity.java:25)
E/AndroidRuntime(27441):    at com.example.test23.WeatherManager.onPostExecute(WeatherManager.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime(27441):    at com.example.test23.WeatherManager.onPostExecute(WeatherManager.java:1)
```

**Edit**
This is my MainActivity that creates the tabs/fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private String tabs[]={"Some String that will display the name of the tabs"};
    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    AdapterView adapterView;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private Activity activity;
    static List<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Item> sports=new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Item> articles=new ArrayList<Item>();
    public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE=1;
        static ParseManager parser=new ParseManager();
    JSONManager jmanager=new JSONManager();
    WeatherManager weather=new WeatherManager();

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterView(fragmentManager));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
    adapterView=new AdapterView(getSupportFragmentManager());
    final android.app.ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar();
    ColorDrawable color=new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cd853f"));
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(color);

    actionbar.setTitle("App title");
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener=new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  

        }
    };
    /*Displaying Tabs for the app */
    for(int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)          actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    parser.execute();//Asynctask
    jmanager.execute();
    weather.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.option1:
            Intent intentContact=new Intent(this,SomeClass.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentContact,TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
              return true;
        case R.id.option2:
            Intent intentAbout=new Intent(this,SomeOtherClass.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentAbout,TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void onRefreshClicked(MenuItem refresh); 
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated, if you need more information please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a breakPoint on the line you have NPE And point the mouse over the variable title and after taht under weather you will see that one of the two is null and will be easier to correct the error and track the nullpointer back to the source

Comment: His problem is much deeper than debugging the NPE. He is trying to instantiate a `Fragment` without using the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @emmanuel explained, `onCreateView` inside fragment in not called until your fragment is attached to an activity. Consequently, textView is not initialized and is null.

You should not call any method on fragment object before displaying it.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();
```

After this line `onCreateView` of fragment gets called and the `view` returned by this is displayed inside `R.id.your_placehodler` on your activity.

Calling `displayWeather` now will not cause NLP.

Comment: I've added the code for the main activity that will create the fragments if that helps

Comment: I sort of understand what you're trying to say, it has to do with the fragment attached with the activity, but I'm trying to figure out where this part goes 
`FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit(); `
I added it in the `onTabSelected` part, since Im working only with the current tab that is showing up. Also, since I'm not attaching/managing the fragments properly, everytime I try to use the context in each fragment is null.

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of problems:

1) You shouldn't instantiate an `Fragment` by calling its constructor. It is Android's job to do that for you via the `FragmentManager` class.

2) You are trying to use the `wa` `Fragment` variable to call a method on it. While this makes sense in regular Java classes. `Fragments` have their own lifecycle. Part of this lifecycle is the `onCreateView()` state. In `onCreateView()` the systems expects you to inflate the layout you want to display. Now, you are creating an instance of an `Fragment` by calling its constructor, and immediately after, you are calling a method that references a `TextView` that hasn't been inflated yet; hence there is no `TextView`so it is `null`.